# How can I store reference of role object in tests at bootstrap using grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to insert user admin data into tests while running the server. Bootstrap class is executing successfully but record is not inserted in table. Here I am pasting my role, user and bootstrap files

**my role domain**

```
package com.mediacast
class Role {    
    static mapWith="mongo"
    String roleType     


    static constraints = {
        roleType(nullable:false,blank:false)
    }
    static mapping = {          
    }
}
```

**my tests domain**

```
package com.mediacast

class Tests {
    static mapWith="mongo"
    //static hasMany = [roles: Role]    
    String userName 
    String password 
    String mailId            
    String pwdSet
    String role
    Role roles
    static constraints = {
        userName nullable:false,blank:false, unique:true        
        mailId blank:false              
    }
    static mapping={
        version false
    }
}
```

**my bootstrap class is**

```
import com.mediacast.User
import com.mediacast.Role
import com.mediacast.Tests
class BootStrap {
    def springSecurityService
    def init = { servletContext ->

        if (!Tests.count()) {       
            createData()                    
        }       
    }
    private void createData(){  
        def roleInstance = Role.findByRoleType("Admin") 
        System.out.println("--------Instance-----------"+roleInstance.roleType);
        //def password = springSecurityService.encodePassword("admin")
        def userSec =new Tests(userName:"admin",password:"admin",mailId:"raghurame@techaffinity.com",roles:roleInstance,pwdSet:"Y").save(flush:true)
        System.out.println("--------Instance-----------"+userSec);
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

It is executing but record is not insert in bootstrap. Please help in this.

Comment: Add `failOnError:true` to your save calls - you'll probably find that something in one of the domain objects is failing validation.

Answer (score 0):

first, in order to debug things, a

```
.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

is better than the standard

```
.save(flush:true)
```

The second one will continue without saving your object if validation fails.

The first one will throw an exception and terminate the startup of your project if validation fails.

It would also be a good trick to throw in some println or better log.debug statements to see if the createDate() is really executed. (`if (!Domain.count())` is not my favorite style - does it work correctly? I prefere `if (Domain.count()==0)`...)

Since I always set the nullable:true|false constraints manually, I don't know what's the default, but I guess this will your problem - the failOnError:true will result in a visible validation exception which will tell you that you have to set the other fields, too...

Please give it a try and write a comment if you don't succeed...

Comment: `nullable` is false by default.